# Gurobi implementing a constraint with the sum of the multiplication of sums with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-programming, gurobi, quadratic-programming

I am using gurobi with gurobipy to implement a linear programm.

While implementing the following constraint, I get a failur.

[image: \forall i \in I: \forall j \in J: y_\text{i,j} \left [ \sum\limits_{a \in A} \left ( \sum\limits_{b \in B} x_\text{i,a,b} * \sum\limits_{b \in B} x_\text{j,a,b} \right ) +1 \right ] = c_\text{i,j}]

With [image] and [image: a] and [image: b] as indices sets.

My minimal example looks like

```
import gurobipy as grb

m = grb.Model()

set_I = range(2)
set_J = range(2)
set_A = range(2)
set_B = range(2)

x_vars = {(i,a,b):m.addVar(vtype=grb.GRB.BINARY, name="x_{}_{}_{}".format(i,a,b)) for i in set_I for a in set_A for b in set_B}
y_vars = {(i,j): m.addVar(vtype=grb.GRB.BINARY, name="y_{}_{}".format(i,j)) for i in set_I for j in set_J}
c_vars = {(i,j): m.addVar(vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="c_{}_{}".format(i,j)) for i in set_I for j in set_J}

for i in set_I:
    for j in set_J:
        m.addConstr(
            lhs=y_vars[i,j] * (grb.quicksum(grb.quicksum(x_vars[i,a,b] for a in set_A for b in set_B) * grb.quicksum(x_vars[j,a,b] for a in set_A for b in set_B))+1),
            sense=grb.GRB.GREATER_EQUAL,
            rhs=c_vars[i,j]
        )
```

and creates

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\stackoverflow.py", line 17, in <module>
    lhs=y_vars[i,j] * (grb.quicksum(grb.quicksum(x_vars[i,a,b] for a in set_A for b in set_B) * grb.quicksum(x_vars[j,a,b] for a in set_A for b in set_B))+1),
  File "src\gurobipy\gurobi.pxi", line 3627, in gurobipy.quicksum
TypeError: 'gurobipy.QuadExpr' object is not iterable
```

Does anyone can help me to fix this problem and implement this constraint correctly?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because optimization modeling questions belong on or.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Greg Glockner: Does questions about the implementation belong to or.stackexchange.com as well? I thought that this is about the implementation with gurobi and python. Therefore it belongs to stackoverflow.

Comment: This isn't an implementation question, it's a modeling one. Products of binary variables should be linearized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to rework this. You can't do `y*x*x` as that is no longer quadratic. You can reformulate using extra variables and equations:

```
z = x*x
y*z
```

I suspect you also have to rewrite the `quicksum(quicksum*quicksum)` using loops.

I agree that the error message is not very informative.

Comment: It should be linearized since x and y are binary variables. That's why I flagged it as a modeling question, not a programming one.

Comment: @GregGlockner Gurobi will linearize this for you.